# Can I use Random method on a class with several instances?

Tags: java, class, random

I'm trying to create a Player class that will randomly pick one of the Combatants in a different class and use it. 
All included in a Pokemon game I'm learning to create.

Right now I'm just trying to figure out if its possible to make a Random method to pick one of the combatants and setting it to player1( for example )

---

```
public class combatantList extends Combatant {
     Combatant Gengar = new Combatant("Gengar", 40, 33, 30, 6);
     Combatant Charizard = new Combatant("Charizard", 45, 35, 100, 6);
     Combatant Venasaur = new Combatant("Venasaur", 40 , 50, 100, 3);
     Combatant Pikachu = new Combatant("Pikachu", 35, 25, 100, 7);
     Combatant Dito = new Combatant("Dito", 10 , 20 ,100, 4); 
 }
```

---

Is the best way to handle these are to set them up in an array? and then use a Random method? or should I be using a random method inside a Battle class or such?

Comment: Make an array or a list is ok.Add the objects in it and then use `Random` class can select one object from the collection randomly

Comment: Unrelated question: why would combatantList extend Combatant? This does not make logical sense since a collection of items should not have the same behavior and state as a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Array is ok,like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
Combatant[] arrays = {Combatant1,Combatant2,Combatant3...};
Combatant randomCombatant = arrays[rand.nextInt(arrays.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ArrayList

```
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Combatant> combatants = new ArrayList<>();
combatants.add(new Combatant("Gengar", 40, 33, 30, 6));
combatants.add(new Combatant("Dito", 40, 353, 300, 6));
combatants.add(new Combatant("Pickachu", 450, 123, 30, 6));

Combatant c = combatants.get(rand.nextInt(arrays.length));
```

Comment: assuming I would like to change the stats of one pokemon - for example - Gengar. Do I need to change the stats in the arrylist or where it was first made?

Comment: no you don't have to, just get the result value from `combatant  c` and use methods like `getter()` or `setter()`, or you could directly call the property like `c.name`

Comment: or you could use this `combatants.get(index).health = 200`

Comment: Combatant c is example for whatever name I wanna use ? such as: Combatant **Player1** = combatants.get(rand.nextInt(arrays.length));

Comment: Or should I need to create a Player1 object in a different class and call the random method there. If my plan is to start a battle Class and to battle 2 different players.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Base on your code above, I do not recommend using `extends combatant`, instead use `import path.to.combatant;`